# In angular how can i activate a pop-up div from multiple?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

In my angular app, I have created a pop-up component with a button. I will use this pop-up button in an extremely complex component. In a scenario, it has seen that I have to use this pop-up component more than 20 times. Now user can click on a pop-up component and based on that, a pop-up div will be visible. Now whenever a user clicks from one pop-up to another one, then I would like to close the previous one. I am having difficulties to achieve this.

> pop-up.html

```
<button style=" display: inline-flex;" (click)="togglePopUp()">Pop Up</button>


<div *ngIf="toggle" class="pop-up">
    I want that, only single pop-up will 
    be activate. and whenever other pop-up will be cliked, this current pop-up 
    will be closed

</div>
```

and

> app.component.html:

```
electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
including versions of Lorem Ipsum. sdf sdf sdf s fsd
<pop-up></pop-up>

<br>
Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
<pop-up></pop-up>
<br>
Where does it come from?
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theot amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
<pop-up></pop-up>
<br>
```

I have also created a stackblitz. Here is the link:
[Please click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dn7hh2?file=src/app/pop-up/pop-up.component.html)

Based on this above example, from `app.component.html`, how can I achieve the desired behavior. How can I close the current pop-up while clicking on another pop-up button, or clicking on outside the current pop-up?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found the solution. HostLister does the trick for me.

```
@HostListener("document:click", ["$event"]) private onDocumentClick(ev) {
    if (!this.hostElement.nativeElement.contains(ev.target)) {
      this.toggle = false;
    }
  }
```

Here I am checking if the click happens inside the component or not. If outside the component then close the pop-up and solved the issue.